# Passing an indefinite number of SSH keys through a Dockerfile securely

Tags: docker, ssh

I want to write a Dockerfile that can process an arbitrary number of SSH keys (different deploy keys for various Github repositories) passed by the user without storing them inside the image. I know you can mount, for example, two keys by using 2 `--mount` commands, but I need it to work regardless of the number of keys I pass; this is because the Dockerfile is designed to pull an arbitrary repository and install its dependencies. I have three potential solutions to this problem:

One idea I had was passing a JSON string mapping repositories to SSH keys and writing individual files to `/dev/shm` and deleting them after using them, but I don't know whether `/dev/shm` is secure (that is to say, whether there is a chance that Docker will store the contents of `/dev/shm` in the history of the completed image or not).

A second idea would be iterating inside the Dockerfile. I don't think this is possible.

A third idea would be somehow passing ssh a string and making it act as an identity file; I don't know enough bash to figure that one out.

Finally, there is the lazy solution of deciding I will never need more than 5 keys and always passing six files, one being a JSON telling me what keys I'm using for what repository and what files are dummies, but that's lazy and hacky and I don't like it.

Does anyone have a way of doing the second or third solutions, or the knowledge to tell me whether the first solution is secure?

Comment: Could you just use a multi staged docker build, pull + dependency install in one stage and then `COPY --from` into the real application image. Then you could just pass the keys into the image and iterate though the directory containing the keys or so.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What do I gain from having the multiple stages? Is the idea that I have a private image stage I don’t share, and then I copy data from it into the shareable image without copying the image history containing the keys?

Comment: Yep. `COPY --from` is mostly used to copy a build artifact without dev dependencies into a frech image. And as far as I understood is that what you need.